# Provding a combined Result from an Array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array

```
data = [ '2016-12-12 pass [pass]',
  '2016-12-12 pass [pass]',
  '2016-12-12 fail [fail]',
  '2016-12-13 fail [fail]',
  '2016-12-14 fail [fail]',
  '2016-12-14 pass [pass]',
  '2016-12-14 pass [pass]',
  '2016-12-15 pass [pass]',
  '2016-12-16 fail [fail]' ]
```

I tried and thought a lot of ways to accomplish using various function but couldn't find out how to achieve this format:

```
2016-12-12 pass:2 fail: 1
2016-12-13 pass:0 fail: 1
2016-12-14 pass:2 fail: 1
2016-12-15 pass:1 fail: 0
2016-12-16 pass:0 fail: 1
```

Comment: You want the output to be a string or an object? the latter is better!

Comment: What have you tried? Using `Array.protoype.reduce` would be a good place to start.

Comment: any format would help me

Comment: you always have the same result repeated between brackets? pass [pass] or fail [fail]

Comment: string `pass` `fail` has nothing to do,  file should be combined by viewing `[]` name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `reduce()` and return array of objects.

```js
var data = [ '2016-12-12 pass [pass]',
  '2016-12-12 pass [pass]',
  '2016-12-12 fail [fail]',
  '2016-12-13 fail [fail]',
  '2016-12-14 fail [fail]',
  '2016-12-14 pass [pass]',
  '2016-12-14 pass [pass]',
  '2016-12-15 pass [pass]',
  '2016-12-16 fail [fail]' ]
  
var result = Object.values(data.reduce(function(r, e) {
  var arr = e.split(' ')
  if(!r[arr[0]]) r[arr[0]] = {date: arr[0], pass: 0, fail: 0} 
  r[arr[0]][arr[1]]++
  return r;
}, {}))

console.log(JSON.stringify(result))
```

If you can't use `Object.values()` you can just use map on object in the end.

```js
var data = [ '2016-12-12 pass [pass]',
  '2016-12-12 pass [pass]',
  '2016-12-12 fail [fail]',
  '2016-12-13 fail [fail]',
  '2016-12-14 fail [fail]',
  '2016-12-14 pass [pass]',
  '2016-12-14 pass [pass]',
  '2016-12-15 pass [pass]',
  '2016-12-16 fail [fail]' ]
  
var result = data.reduce(function(r, e) {
  var arr = e.split(' ')
  if(!r[arr[0]]) r[arr[0]] = {date: arr[0], pass: 0, fail: 0} 
  r[arr[0]][arr[1]]++
  return r;
}, {})

result = Object.keys(result).map(e => result[e])

console.log(JSON.stringify(result))
```

Comment: It's worth noting that `Object.values` is not supported in Internet Explorer or Safari.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way:

```js
const data = [
  '2016-12-12 pass [pass]',
  '2016-12-12 pass [pass]',
  '2016-12-12 fail [fail]',
  '2016-12-13 fail [fail]',
  '2016-12-14 fail [fail]',
  '2016-12-14 pass [pass]',
  '2016-12-14 pass [pass]',
  '2016-12-15 pass [pass]',
  '2016-12-16 fail [fail]',
];

const result = {};

data.forEach(item => {
  const [date, passFail] = item.split(' ');
  
  if (!(date in result)) {
    result[date] = { pass: 0, fail: 0 };
  }
  
  result[date][passFail] += 1;
});

console.log(result);
```

As you can see in the output, this returns an object whose property names are dates and whose values are objects with the properties `pass` and `fail`.

Note that you could use `reduce` instead of `forEach` to save a line, but `reduce` is sort of pointless if you're mutating the object anyway, so I've used `forEach` for simplicity.

Note also that although in practice (i.e. in current JS engines) objects retain their properties' insertion order, strictly speaking JavaScript object properties are unordered. If you want to be strict about order, you'll need to use an array, in which case the simplest solution would be an after-the-fact transformation like the following:

```js
const result = {
  "2016-12-12": { pass: 2, fail: 1 },
  "2016-12-13": { pass: 0, fail: 1 },
  "2016-12-14": { pass: 2, fail: 1 },
  "2016-12-15": { pass: 1, fail: 0 },
  "2016-12-16": { pass: 0, fail: 1 },
};

const resultArray = Object.keys(result).sort()
                      .map(key => [ key, result[key] ]);

console.log(resultArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `reduce` to hash the dates into an object like this: (note the output is an object of object)

```js
function group(arr) {
  return arr.reduce(function(hash, e) {      // for each element e in the array arr
    var parts = e.split(' ');                // split the element e by space
    if(hash[parts[0]]) {                     // if the date (part 0) is already hashed
      hash[parts[0]][parts[1]]++;            // then increment the equivalent pass or fail (part 1)
    }
    else {                                   // if not
      hash[parts[0]] = {pass: 0, fail: 0};   // create a new object for the date
      hash[parts[0]][parts[1]]++;            // increment its pass or fail value
    }
    return hash;
  }, {});
}

var array = ['2016-12-12 pass [pass]',
  '2016-12-12 pass [pass]',
  '2016-12-12 fail [fail]',
  '2016-12-13 fail [fail]',
  '2016-12-14 fail [fail]',
  '2016-12-14 pass [pass]',
  '2016-12-14 pass [pass]',
  '2016-12-15 pass [pass]',
  '2016-12-16 fail [fail]'
];

console.log(group(array));
```